# Getting the datarow context or value parent in a xceed grid column group value template?

Tags: xaml, data-binding, datagrid, datatemplate, xceed

I am using an xceed `DataGrid` but I don't believe that matters here.  What I need is how to get the databinding correct.  I have a `DataGrid` column as follows:

```
<xcdg:Column FieldName="TestFieldValue"             
             Visible="False" Title="TestTitle"
             GroupValueTemplate="{StaticResource TestFieldGroupTemplate}"/>
```

I am using a `DataTemplate` as follows:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type testNamespace:TestFieldRecord}" 
              x:Key="TestFieldGroupTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type xcdg:DataRow}}, 
                              Path=DataContext, 
                              Converter={StaticResource TestFieldValueConverter}}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

First off, the value the property tied to this column field is just a long.  The DataType here on the `DataTemplate` is actually the parent class of the column field property.  An odd thing is if I just bind the text property in the data template like `Text={Binding Converter={StaticResource TestFieldValueConverter}}`, the converter still gets hit but with the long value from the column.

What I need here is to either bind to the `DataRow`'s context, or to the the parent of the column `TestFieldValue`, which is the `testNamespace:TestFieldRecord`.  Any find ancestor attempts have led me to no longer hitting my converter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the Snoop tool to look at the tree and DataContext to see what's happening.

Going up a couple of levels in the tree, the DataContext will be a Xceed Group.
This group has a **collection** of items.
Your TestFieldGroupTemplate is applying to a Group.

So the main question is where is the group title coming from?

If you just want to change the group text, you can use a DataTemplate targeting Group.
(In the paid version TableflowView this will replace all their standard stuff).

Eg this passes the Group and DataGridControl to an IMultiValueConverter converter:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type xcdg:Group}">
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AnExampleConverter}">
                <Binding Path="DataContext" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type xcdg:DataGridControl}}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```